# Why does Facebook hate my image?

Tags: image, facebook

I have a small 100x100 pixel image at this location: http://quoteth.is/images/bigquote.png

Facebook just hates this image for some reason. On my Facebook app page, when trying to upload it, it fails with no error message.  When I use this image as the image link when posting to a user's wall, sometimes it appears, sometimes it doesn't.

What could the reason be for Facebook not liking an image?  I know they support PNGs, 100x100 is the size that they suggested. And it's a small file size.  What else could it be?

Thanks!

Comment: How is this a progamming question?

Comment: Nathan, could you give some more context please? Where exactly are you trying to upload the image? Can you share a link to the page where you're using it as the og:image? You might want to run that page through the Linter (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint).

Comment: The issue isn't just with uploading, that was just to add context. But to answer your question, it's the "edit your app" page on Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APPID/summary

Comment: Also, the real problem is in trying to Post to a user's wall. I include an absolute url to specify the image to be used in the Post, and about half the time it works fine, and the other half of the time, there is just a missing image on the post.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try to lint your app url.
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/

Comment: I did, and I am missing og: elements, which I will fix. But I'm specifying the full absolute url when I make the post, and sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. Today I used it twice, once it got the image, the other time it didn't.